# How is a ReaderWriterLock shared amongst threads? Is it implemented with a singleton?

Tags: .net, readerwriterlock

When you want to use a `ReaderWriterLock` you declare it like this:

`ReaderWriterLock rwLock = new ReaderWriterLock;`

Well if you are doing that for all your different threads that are going to access some resource that you want to protect, they (presumably) are all using differnt ReaderWriterLock instances.

How is the ReaderWriterLock instance shared amongs threads?

Also, as a bonus, can someone confirm for me that what you are *really* "locking" is the ReaderWriterLock state, not any resource. Unlike `lock(someResourceToLock)`, you aren't locking anything but the ReaderWriterLock instance's state (whether it is in read or write mode, and whether you are allowed to read and write yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the `ReaderWriterLock rwLock = new ReaderWriterLock` **per thread** or **per method** (i.e. as a method variable), then your code is most-likely broken. It is not a singleton; it relies on all threads accessing the protected data using the *same* lock. This is most commonly achieved by placing the lock in a field, i.e.

```
class Foo {
    ReaderWriterLock rwLock = new ReaderWriterLock();
    // lots of code accessing the rwLock field for this instance
}
```

Also - maybe consider `ReaderWriterLockSlim` in many scenarios; less overhead. Re your follow-up; when acquiring the lock you are changing the internal state (in a thread-safe manner) to preserve the "many-readers `nand` single-writer" expectation (perhaps blocking until that is possible, i.e. conflicting locks have been withdrawn).

Comment: Thanks. The examples in my book are pretty poor then. . . So if you place the lock in a field, would you want it to be static, so that every thread that accesses the class would be using the same lock?

Comment: @Richard - static and threads are orthogonal; usually you want every thread that accesses the same **instance** of the class to use the same lock, so it would be an instance (i.e. non-static) field. If you are trying to protect `static` state, then a `static` lock is desirable - but try to avoid using too much `static` state - it is usually a bad sign.

Comment: Ok, I see, except I am not sure what you mean by orthogonal (the only part of what you said that I don't understand).

Comment: @Richard [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality#Computer_science) i.e. mostly unrelated. Actually, that's not *quite* true, as there is a common expectation that static data should be thread-safe, but since we should be avoiding too much static data *anyway* that is usually moot

Comment: Thank you, as always I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions.

Answer (score 2):

> How is the ReaderWriterLock instance shared amongs threads?

Create a *single* instance of [`ReaderWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) and use it from all threads that are accessing the shared resource you want to protect.

> Also, as a bonus, can someone confirm for me that what you are really "locking" is the ReaderWriterLock state, not any resource. Unlike lock(someResourceToLock), you aren't locking anything but the ReaderWriterLock instance's state

You really are locking.

`lock(obj) { ... }` is just a short cut for (simplified here, the real implementation has some additional subtleties to handle edge cases):

```
Monitor.Enter(obj)
  ...
try {
} finally {
  Monitor.Exit(obj);
}
```

using the field in every reference type to hold the state used by [`Monitor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx).

---

As Marc notes, consider [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) unless you need the fairness (threads guaranteed to enter in the order they starting waiting) that [`ReaderWriterLock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) gives.

Comment: What I asking for confirmation on was that ReaderWriterLock doesn't lock any _resource_, it is locking itself, essentially. Is that correct?

Comment: `Monitor.Enter` / `Monitor.Exit`, no? Note that the implementation changes between C# and .NET versions too (i.e. C# 4 will try to use a different API if available, falling back to the one indicated otherwise)

Comment: @RichardDesLonde: Both ways of stating it work in English, but that's a limitation of English :-). I would normally talk about using the `ReaderWriterLock` instance to lock the resource because the resource is the important thing. However you are right in that the `ReaderWriterLock` doesn't itself have any information or state representing what you are using it to protect.

Comment: @Marc: clearly I do need that coffee :-(. The use of the lockTaken boolean is what I was avoiding with the parenthetical comment.